# Getting anonymous type when converting list to DataTable

Tags: c#

I have a list where I select column `TaskId`(Global variable) and `EmpGuid`(from list) like:

```
 var parameterstest = assignNotificationTableType.Select(x => new { TaskId, x.EmpGuid }).ToList();
```

So if I debug I get something like this:

[image]

Now I create method to convert it to DataTable like:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
        {

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

            //Get all the properties

            PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (Props.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
                {
                    if (GetDefault(prop.PropertyType.FullName) != null)
                    {
                        //Setting column names as Property names
                        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dataTable.Columns.Add("myColName");
            }
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();
                    if (Props.Length > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
                        {
                            if (GetDefault(prop.PropertyType.FullName) != null)
                            {
                                //inserting property values to datatable rows
                                dr[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item, null) ?? GetDefault(prop.PropertyType.FullName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //inserting property values to datatable rows
                        dr[0] = item;
                    }

                    dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }

            //put a breakpoint here and check datatable

            return dataTable;

        }

        public static object GetDefault(string dataType)
        {

            if (dataType.Contains("System.String"))
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            if (dataType.Contains("System.Boolean"))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (dataType.Contains("System.Decimal"))
            {
                return 0.0;
            }
            if (dataType.Contains("System.DateTime"))
            {
                return DateTime.MinValue;
            }
            if (dataType.Contains("System.Int64"))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if (dataType.Contains("System.Guid"))
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (dataType.Contains("System.Int16"))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if (dataType.Contains("Int32"))
            {
                return 0;

            }
            if (dataType.Contains("System.Object"))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

But when I try to use as:

```
 var parameters = ToDataTable(assignNotificationTableType.Select(x => new { TaskId, x.EmpGuid }).ToList());
```

Variable returns `{<>f__AnonymousType42}` instead DataTable

[image]

I don't know why it returns AnonymousType. Some one know what is the issue there?

**UPDATE**

[image]

As you can see Anonymous type datatable count rows correctly but ItemArray is always zero instead my values

Comment: You are using anonymous type `.Select(x => new { TaskId, x.EmpGuid })`.

Comment: But why my rows of dataTable counts 2(that's correct) but ItemArray its 0? instead values of row? I'll update my question with picture of that @Llazar

Answer (score 0):

I solved it changing my Convert DataTable method to:

```
public static DataTable ToSingleDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
                TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
            {
                PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
            }
            object[] values = new object[props.Count];
            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
                }
                table.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return table;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

With `dynamic` variables, the C# compiler adds code to figure out the type of the variable and perform necessary operations on it, all at run time.

Generics in C# are reified at compile-time; that is, if you have `List<T>` and construct it with `new List<int>()`, during the compilation phase a new completely class (named, I believe, "List`1[Int32]") will be generated and included in the binary. The invocation `new List<int>()` will be replaced with the constructor of this new class (contrast this with Java, which does type erasure on its generics rather than type reification, so everything ends up an `ArrayList` containing `Object`s, effectively an `ArrayList<Object>`).

Maybe you see where this is going. To compile your function that creates a `DataTable<T>`, the compiler has to know the type of `T` *at compile time* - precisely what `dynamic` has already told the compiler to defer and figure out at run time. Therefore, every time you say `DataTable<T>` where `T` is `dynamic`, the compiler has to put in a placeholder: hence the AnonymousType. The debugger doesn't know more, because the debug symbols are added at compile time, too.

If you can't view the items contained in the DataTable by clicking the disclosure triangle, you should still be able to view them if you go to the Debugger command line, with `? parameters` and/or `? paramaters.Columns[<name>]`, etc